# remove apps with htc bootloader unlocked

Tags: htc-evo, bootloader

Will just unlocking the bootloader per HTC website allow me to remove apps like Blockbuster, Nova, etc on an EVO 4G?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unlocking your bootloader allows you to flash unsigned images to your device, but it doesn't (in and of itself) give you root permissions which you need to remove bloatware. However, having the ability to flash unsigned images makes it very easy to gain root via a custom recovery, so unlocking your bootloader can often greatly simplify the process.

If you need instructions for getting root, there's a fairly exhaustive guide [here](http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-all-things-root/488901-revised-rooting-gingerbread-2-3-5-dummies-guide.html).